# Driver fails to install with error 0xE000024B

Tags: windows-7, drivers, certificate

We have a driver that is built and signed in-house.
Recently, we have been having issues installing this on windows 7. Initially it was missing certificates and that was resolved by installing the root and intermediate certificates. Signtool checks are all successful.
But now I get this error during installation:

```
Failed to verify file 'WdfCoInstaller01009.dll' against catalog. Catalog = avp3ioc2.cat, Error = 0xE000024B
!!!  sto:                          Catalog did not contain file hash. File is likely corrupt or a victim of tampering.
```

I checked the catalog file and verified the thumbprint against that of WdfCoInstaller01009.dll. Everything matches.

What maybe causing this? Could I resolve this without re-signing the drivers (it's a long process)? Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S. The windows partition has EWF enabled. The driver is installed via DiInstallDriver.

Answer (score 1):

The .cat file contains a checksum of all of the driver files.  If you
only sign the .cat, then it only covers the original file (like a .sys file).  You can't copy and use a new one unless you sign that one too.

There are two different signature checks. One is the install-time
check, which applies only to PnP driver packages.  This check is done on
all of the systems, 32 and 64-bit. In this case, the .cat matters. If the .cat file is WHQL signed, install is silent. If .cat is signed by your own you'll get a warning ("do you trust this ...)" . If your .cat file is unsigned or missing, you get the "unsigned driver" warning. The user can bypass any of those and allow the driver to be installed.

The other one is the kernel-mode code signing, which is done each and
every time the driver is loaded, but exclusively on 64-bit systems.  For this
check, you can sign the .sys driver files, or if you have a driver package, you
can sign the .cat files. For this check, you must use a class 3
code-signing certificate and you must use the appropriate
cross-certificate from Microsoft to cross into their certificate
domain.  You can check whether you have done this correctly using
"signtool verify /kp /v".  If you do not see the "Microsoft Code
Verification Root", then you probably did not use a cross-certificate. This is a big pain, I know.

Now that this is cleared up, the answer to your question is YES, you will need to re-sign the driver.

Comment: Thank you Overmind. That makes things a lot clearer. We are using a kernel mode driver and signtool verify confirms that it has been cross signed. Coming back to the issue, yes we have only signed the .cat file and we haven't changed any files. The thumbprints match the SHA-1 of the inf, sys and coInstaller. But on our test machine with Enhanced write protection enabled, I get the error mentioned in the question. Why would it say "catalog does not contain a file hash" when it clearly has three thumbprints for the three files? Could the versions of WdfCoInstaller already installed,affect this?

Comment: Are you sure the .inf was not altered ? If the .sys is still the original, then I don't think anything else but the .inf could be the cause. Enhanced write protection could cause something not to be actually written. Better compare the deployed files with the originals using a decent file manager, just to make sure nothing strange happened during their deployment. Also, try to copy the .cat file itself from a functional machine. The actual .cat can be corrupted.